# Documentation on the personalized prediction data

Tags: feature-request, support, profile-page, prediction-data

The new [Personalized Predication Data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/prediction-data) seems very nice to show relevant content, and the ability to download the data is excellent. It gives a feeling of trust.

However, the downloaded data doesn't make any sense without documentation. Can there be a link to a page explaining what the figures mean?

Comment: This seems to be related to this [blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/targeted-jobs-for-stack-overflow/) (Thanks [Andrew T.](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3087543#3087543) for pointing to it).